# c# - Publishing Error / File Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to publish my website in VS 2015, but I am receiving the following error:

> Copying file Views\Shared\_StockQuotePartial.cshtml to
>   obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Views\Shared\_StockQuotePartial.cshtml
>   failed. Could not find file 'Views\Shared\_StockQuotePartial.cshtml'.

I have checked the Views\Shared folder (with all items showing) and no file named _StockQuotePartial.cshtml exists.  I have also deleted the obj and bin folders and attempted to republish, but with no success.  In addition, I have looked for references in the .csproj file and found non.

Any idea as to why I am getting this error for a file that does not exist / how I can resolve it?

Comment: Have you checked whether the files exists within your `.csproj` and `.sln`?

Comment: Double check: on *View folder* for Shared_StockQuotePartial.cshtml and *NOT on Shared folder* (notice the underscore on the name..)

Comment: Underscores should have been showing up... fixed to correct this.  File does not exist in csproj or sln

Comment: I suggest you could also check the publish profile. As far as I know, the publish profile could also write copy command to copy the file when publishing. More details, you could refer to this article:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild the project and then publish it ..

Comment: Tried that and it didn't fix it.  I can build my website and launch it on local host, but it refuses to publish.