# I'm getting an error when publishing my project

Tags: c#, asp.net, publish

I compile my project, no errors appear, but I get this error when publishing. When I check the file path, there is no problem. Does anyone know what's causing the problem?

```
Severity Code Description Project Path File Line Column Hide Status
Error obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Contents\Admin\bower_components\contextmenu\documentation\website\original-theme\sass\_theme_font_awesome_compatibility.sass file Copying to .sass failed. Part of path 'obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Contents\Admin\bower_components\contextmenu\documentation\website\original-theme\sass\_theme_font_awesome_compatibility.sass' could not be found. PaperArc 0 0
```

I tried deleting the bin folder and tried deleting the package folder, but I didn't get any results.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question so that we can reproduce the situation with the least amount of code. Or at least format the error so that it's not in a fake table. Also, read the error; it says a file in the obj folder cannot be found. Have you looked to see if that file exists?

Comment: [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43732097/1997232)?

Comment: I have a feeling the `_theme_font_awesome_compatibility.sass` part may be the issue. Can you rename without the underscore?